# NHibernate - Why does Delete() call fail to delete but delete through HQL works?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, db2, ibm-midrange

Considering the following code blocks, why does call to HQL work but call to delete() not work? As a background, I'm using NHibernate over IBM.Data.DB2.Iseries driver. Come to find out, journaling on the AS400 is turned off so I can't use transactions. I'm not the AS400 admin or know anything about it so I don't know if having journaling turned off (not opening transactions) is causing this problem or not. Do I absolutely need the ability to open transactions if I'm calling Delete() or other NHibernate functions?

```
//This Does not work - no error and no deletes
public static void Delete(Object Entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //using(ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            //{
                session.Delete(Entity);
                //tx.Commit();                    
                session.Close();                    
            //}
        }
    }

//This does work
public static void Delete(Object Entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //commented out transaction control because throws error because
            //journaling is not turned on the AS400
            //using(ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            //{
                session.CreateQuery("delete MyDAO p where p.MyDAOID = :MyDAOID").SetString("MyDAOID", ((MyDAO)Entity).MyDAOID.ToString()).ExecuteUpdate();                
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception and what is the message?
If you don't get an exception, what sql will be generated by session.delete?

Comment: Paco, I don't receive an exception and no delete query is produced. Please see my other response to this post (I posted after seeing your comment). If I call the Get function to retrieve the object within a session, then tell it to delete within that session, it then produces the Delete query.

Comment: So, why don't I receive an exception?  I am learning that, because I queried for a list of objects in one session and then closed it, and am trying to delete the object from a different session, it's not working--because it's not within the same unit of work I guess. However, shouldn't it be kind enough to throw and exception so I know that my object didn't delete?

Answer (score 8):

Try calling `session.Flush()` after you delete, but before you close the session. And you don't need to explicitly close the session:

```
using (var session = ...)
{
    entity.Delete();
    session.Flush();
}
```

Comment: This did work for me, and I'd love to know why. I use the same session to get all my entities. I have a feeling it's because it's a more rare case to want to have the delete happen before the transaction is committed. NHibernate probably intends to just have it all happen later, which normally would be okay.

Answer (score 1):

**After delving further into this, I found that this works but why?:**

```
public static void Delete(Object Entity)
{
    using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {       
         MyDAO p = session.Get<MyDAO>(Entity.ID);
         session.Delete(p);
         session.Flush();                                    
    }            
}
```

Here is my scenario: I have previously queried for a list of objects which I populated into a Grid. For that query process, I opened/closed a session. Upon calling my delete function, I take that object and pass it into this function for a separate open/close session process. To stir things up a bit, I added the call to this new delete asking it to get the object first (the one I want deleted), then call delete. Now it sends the delete query to the database and the object is in fact deleted. Why is this?

Is this because my original query of objects was opened within a different session and then deleted in another? Does this have anything to do with the unit of work. Should I open my session for my grid, leave it open until my form closes so all deletes work inside that session? I was under the impression that sessions should be opened/closed quickly. I'm confused.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't open a new session for each data access method. You should open a new one for every time a user clicks a save or delete button in the UI. Use one session per unit of work. When you don't you lose the caching of the session and you will have to attach the objects retrieved by previous sessions to the session again. 
2. You can change the session factory to "auto-flush"

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused by point 1 of your comment. You state that I shouldn't open a new session for each data access method but you then state that I should for each save/delete which in my terminology are data access methods. Please clarify. So, what is considered a unit of work when working with a form that has a grid? Is one uow querying the data and another uow the deletion of the data or is a uow the querying of the data and also the deletion/edit (one piece of data or all)? I attempted opening a session, querying my data/populating my grid, delete then flush, and that worked.

Comment: I can't give you an answer to that: it can be both depending on what the data is and what the user is doing with it. Martin Fowler writes about it in Patterns of Entrerprice Applications