# NHibernate does not delete entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

In the TestFixtureTearDown-part of an NUnit test I try to delete some test-entities created in the TestFixtureSetUp-part. I use the following code

```
        sessionFactory = NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory(cssc["DefaultTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        uow = new NHibernateUnitOfWork(sessionFactory);

        var g = reposGebruiker.GetByName(gebruiker.GebruikerNaam);
        reposGebruiker.Delete(g);

        var k = reposKlant.GetByName(klant.Naam);
        reposKlant.Delete(k);

        // Commit changes to persistant storage
        uow.Commit();
```

However, after the commit, the two entities were still in the database. After searching on I came across [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676670/nhibernate-why-does-delete-call-fail-to-delete-but-delete-through-hql-works) on SO and so I added:

```
        uow.Session.Flush();
```

However, still the entities remain in the DB. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is?

Comment: Hard to tell. do "g" and "k" have a value (I forgot what NHibernate does when attempting to delete null)? Do they actually have the value you expect? IIRC, Flush() just flushes statements, and is automatically called before a commit by Commit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the UoW class you're using, but my projects are implemented using ISession.BeginTransaction and ISession.Transaction.Commit in a helper like this:

> public void CreateContext(Action logic) 
>   {
>
> ```
>   ISession.BeginTransaction();
>   logic();
>   ISession.Transaction.Commit();
> ```
>
> }

And then:

> CreateContext(() =>
>   Session.Delete(someObject));

This should work.

I want to mention that this is an example, and you'd want to make some abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

How are the repositories created? In for the delete to succeed, the objects must be loaded in the same UoW (ISession) in which the Delete command is issued. The `Delete` method makes the objects non-persistent and marks them for deletion.